# ClassCastExeption Error when Trying to Get Cell Location Using Telephony Class

Tags: android, location, telephony

I received some Reports on Google Play(from the same User) about CdmaCellLocation :

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation
```

this is a Service that Report the Approximativ User Location using Cell Network , Please Notice that its 100% Working for me and i had not any other Report about this Bug , Here the Code from the onStart() :

```
  public class ServiceLocation extends Service{
int myLatitude , myLongitude;
private String str2;    
static SharedPreferences prefs;
private String numtosend;

public int onStartCommand(Intent itn,int num1, int num2){

     prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 
             Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(isAirplaneModeOn(this)){
            stopSelf();
        }


    Bundle extras = itn.getExtras();

     if(extras.containsKey("ExtraName") != true){
     str2 = itn.getStringExtra("Number");
     }
     location(str2);

     return 0;


   }
```

Here the location Method Code :

```
 public void location(String num){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     if(telephonyManager.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT){
     numtosend = "Phone Number (If Avaible) : " + " " + telephonyManager.getLine1Number() + "  " + " Sim Serial : " + telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber() + "  " + "IMEI : " + telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
     }
     else {
         numtosend = this.getResources().getString(R.string.txtNoSimCard) + telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
     }
     GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();


        int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
        int lac = cellLocation.getLac();

        if(RqsLocation(cid, lac)){




      if(str2.equals("") != true && str2.equals(null) != true) {
      SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(num, null, this.getResources().getString(R.string.txtGPSPosition) + "(40-250 Meters Accuracy) : "+"http://maps.google.com/?q="+String.valueOf((float)myLatitude/1000000) +","+String.valueOf((float)myLongitude/1000000), null, null);

        }


        if(gmailaccount.equals("") != true && gmailpass.equals(null) != true){



                 P m = new P(gmailaccount , gmailpass);

                             String[] Mail = {mail};
                             m.setTo(Mail);
                             m.setFrom("AnonymousMail@gmail.com"); 
                             m.setSubject("Location");
                             m.setBody(this.getResources().getString(R.string.txtGPSPosition) + "(~300 Meters Accuracy) : " + "http://maps.google.com/?q="+String.valueOf((float)myLatitude/1000000) +","+String.valueOf((float)myLongitude/1000000) + " " + str2 + "  " + numtosend); 

                             try {
                                if(m.send()){
                                     stopSelf();
                                 }
                                else {

                                     if(str2.equals("") != true) {
                                            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(str2, null, "Impossible to Send a Message to your Emergency Mail Address !", null, null);
                                                 }
                                     stopSelf();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



    }

        }

      else{
          if(str2.equals("") != true && str2.equals(null) != true) {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(num, null, this.getResources().getString(R.string.txtInternetOffLocation), null, null);
          }

          if(gmailaccount.equals("") != true && gmailpass.equals(null) != true){
             P m = new P(gmailaccount , gmailpass);

                         String[] Mail = {mail};
                         m.setTo(Mail);
                         m.setFrom("AnonymousMail@gmail.com"); 
                         m.setSubject("Location");
                                m.setBody(this.getResources().getString("Internet Off)); 

                         try {
                            if(m.send()){
                                 stopSelf();
                             }
                            else {

                                 if(str2.equals("") != true) {

                                             }
                                 stopSelf();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
          }

          }



        stopSelf();

}
```

And finaly The LogCat From Google Play :

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ServiceLocation@4051b930 with Intent {            cmp=com.xxx.xxx.xxx/.ServiceLocation (has extras) }: java.lang.ClassCastException:                 android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2052)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:994)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation
   at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ServiceLocation.location(ServiceLocation.java:83)
   at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ServiceLocation.onStartCommand(ServiceLocation.java:53)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2039)
  ... 10 more
```

Do you Think its a Problem with the Phone Provider , or if its come from Tablet ?

[Off-Topic] By the way , where & how can i Report this :

[image]

Comment: Is this `GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();` line `ServiceLocation.location(ServiceLocation.java:83)`?  Have you tested your application on a CDMA phone?

Comment: Yes this line , no , i dont Think , i have No Cdma Phone

Comment: My guess is that you are going to need to determine which type of phone it is and use [CdmaCellLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html) if the device is a CDMA phone and your existing code for GSM phones.

Comment: yes , i am going to Call stopSelf() if this is a CDMA Phone , Thanks for your Answer . P.S : about the Screen ?

Comment: Do you mean the profanity in the error reports shown in your screenshot?  I really can't answer that as I am very new to Android programming and I haven't published any applications to Google Play.  My gut feeling is that it probably isn't worth the effort.  If you aren't going to support CDMA phones you should put a disclaimer in your store posting to minimize frustration.  Any chance you could just add the CDMA code for CDMA phones?  You should checkout [Keynote's Device Anywhere testing product](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/da-free-product-overview.html) to test your GSM code.

Comment: Thanks you , i will Use the Answer of @Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
```

This is an unsafe cast. Your code assumes that this method will always return an instance of `GsmCellLocation` but that is not the case. There are two types of cellular networks. GSM and CDMA.

If the phone is running on a CDMA network then `getCellLocation()` will return an instance of `CdmaCellLocation`.

You can call `telephonyManager.getPhoneType()` to get information about the type of the radio used by the device. This method will return one of four values:

**PHONE_TYPE_NONE** - the device doesn't have a cellular radio. It could be a tablet without a 3G modem for instance. `getCellLocation()` will return `null`.

**PHONE_TYPE_GSM** - the device has a GSM radio. You can safely call `(GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();`

**PHONE_TYPE_CDMA** - the device has a GSM radio. You can safely call `(CdmaCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();`

**PHONE_TYPE_SIP** - the device is using SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) for communication. `getCellLocation()` will return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Researching this you can determine the phone type using the `getPhoneType()` of the TelephonyManager class.

I would try the following:

```
switch( telephonyManager.getPhoneType() ) {

    case PHONE_TYPE_GSM: {
         // Handle GSM phone
         GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
         break;
    }
    case PHONE_TYPE_CDMA: {
         // Handle CDMA phone
         CdmaCellLocation cellLocation = (CdmaCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
         break;
    }
    default: {
        // can't do cell location
    }
```

Comment: and this :     (CDMA) cid = cellLocation.getBaseStationLatitude();
        lac = cellLocation.getBaseStationLongitude(); == this (GSM)      cid = cellLocation.getCid();
        lac = cellLocation.getLac(); ?

Comment: I think your code is missing the break statements at the end of each cases ;-)